# JQuery drop list item in menu

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I couldn't think of a better title, my apologies.
Basically what I'm trying to ask:

I have several lists in which I drag and drop li's.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Extract of my jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"

      //update method here normally

    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

Now I also have a menu and I would like to be able to also drop a li in a menu item so I can post the values in another PHP function the menu item is linked to.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Menu</a> </li>
</ul>
```

I've made a fiddle with a small example of what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbqa7bwb/

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: This as nothing to do with the actual problem and won't help you solve it but there is something semantically paradoxal willing to sort elements in an `<ul>` :-) Better use an `<ol>` in that case. (as it would actually be semantically better in many cases, including navigations where you obviously have some kind of order)

Comment: Please go through the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zbqa7bwb/1/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this isn't exactly what I mean. What I still try to achieve is when I drop an item on a menu, I want to do a POST request to a PHP function on another page, but the menu may not change

Comment: too bad you lost 100 rep for this... Somebody would've answered it within 10 minutes if you had explained properly...

Comment: BTW you can edit the question and ask something else since there are no answers and 6 days of bounty left... sshhhhh...

Comment: Yup, I know, and if it wasn't friday afternoon I would've fixed it myself in 10 min too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself by doing something like this. Maybe this will help someone out in the future:

```
$(".dayMenu").droppable({
  accept: '.ui-state-default',

  drop: function() {
    alert('my POST here');
  }
});
```

Updated fiddle to clear things up:

http://jsfiddle.net/zbqa7bwb/2/